# The line $DN$ bisects the line segment $AC$ if $AD=BC$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

Consider a circle with diameter $AB$.  A point $D$ on the circle is chosen arbitrarily such that $D\ne A,B$.   A point $C\in AB$ is also chosen arbitrarily such that $C\ne A,B$. Draw $CH$ perpendicular to $AD$ at $H$. The internal angular bisector of $\angle DAB$ intersects the circle at $E$, and intersects $CH$ at $F$.  The line $DF$ intersects circle again at $N$.

> Prove that the points $N$, $C$, and $E$  are collinear.  If $AD=BC$, then prove that $DN$ intersects $AB$ at the midpoint $I$ of $AC$.

---

I proved $N,C,E$  are collinear by cyclic quadrilateral and two congruent triangles. But I have no idea for the second problem.

[image]

Comment: It is highly recommended that you attach a picture for a geometry problem.  It attracts more users if you put a picture in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, i fixed it.

Comment: Do not use semicolon ; to separate items within the same sentence.  Usually, a semicolon is used to separate sentences that are connected to the same idea.  And good that you have put a picture, because there is a grammatical error in your original problem statement which can make people interpret the question completely differently.

Comment: And if you could put your proof for the first part of the problem, then it would be best.  It may give some user an idea how to help you with the second part of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reflect $A$ across $D$ to a new point $Q$. Then $\triangle QDE\cong \triangle ECB$ (sas).

Since $$\angle QEC = \angle DEB $$ we see that quadrilateral $ACEQ$ is cyclic, so $$\angle QCE =\angle QAE =  \angle DAE = \angle DNE$$ so $QC||DN$. Now since $D$ halves $AQ$ the line $DI$ is a middle line for triangle $QAC$ and thus it halves $AC$.

Comment: Cool!  Do you have a geometric proof of the first part?  It would be great if you could share.

Comment: How?  This proof assumes $AD=BC$, but the collinearity is true even if $AD\neq BC$.

Comment: Since $FC||BD$ quadrilateral $ANCF$ is also cyclic: $$\angle ACF = \angle ABD = \angle AND = \angle ANF$$ Now do some angle chase...

Comment: Marvelous!  Thanks for your work.

Answer (score 2):

This is a trigonometric solution, so it is not very nice. 
 In this part of my answer, I shall prove the first part of the problem.

[image]

Let $\theta:=\angle ABD$, $\alpha:=\angle HFD$, and $\beta:=\angle BEC$.  Write $d$ for the diameter of the circle (i.e., $d=AB$), and $l$ for the length of $BC$.  We see that
$$CH\parallel BD\text{ so that }DH=l\sin(\theta)\,.$$
Now, $\angle DAE=\angle EAB=\dfrac{\pi}{4}-\dfrac{\theta}{2}$.  Hence,
$$\angle AFD=\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\theta}{2}+\alpha\,.$$
Since $AD=d\sin(\theta)$, we get
$$\frac{DF}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}=\frac{d\sin(\theta)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\theta}{2}+\alpha\right)}$$
via the Law of Sines on the triangle $ADF$.  Thus,
$$\sin(\alpha)=\frac{DH}{DF}=\frac{l\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\theta}{2}+\alpha\right)}{d\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}\,.\tag{1}$$

Note that $\angle AEB=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, so
$$BE=d\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\,.$$
Applying the Law of Sines on the triangle $BEC$ yields
$$\frac{l}{\sin(\beta)}=\frac{d\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\theta}{2}+\beta\right)}\,,\tag{2}$$
noting that $\angle EBD=\angle EAD=\dfrac{\pi}{4}-\dfrac{\theta}{2}$.  Consequently,
$$\frac{\sin(\beta)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\theta}{2}+\beta\right)}=\frac{l}{d\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}=\frac{\sin(\alpha)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\theta}{2}+\alpha\right)}\,,$$
using (1) and (2).  Using the trigonometric identity $\sin(x)\sin(y)=\dfrac{1}{2}\big(\cos(x-y)-\cos(x+y)\big)$, we obtain
$$\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\theta}{2}+\alpha-\beta\right)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\theta}{2}-\alpha+\beta\right)\,.$$
Hence,
$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\sin(\alpha-\beta)=0\,.$$
Because $0<\theta<\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, we get $\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\dfrac{\theta}{2}\right)>0$, making $\sin(\alpha-\beta)=0$.  As $\alpha$ and $\beta$ belong to the interval $\left(0,\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$, the condition $\sin(\alpha-\beta)=0$ implies that $\alpha=\beta$.

Finally. we see that $\angle AEB=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, so
$$\angle AEC=\frac{\pi}{2}-\beta=\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha=\angle ADN=\angle AEN\,.$$
This shows that $E$, $C$, and $N$ are collinear.

---

I shall now prove the second part of the problem.  In fact, I shall prove a stronger result that $DN$ meets $AB$ at the midpoint $I$ of $AC$ if and only if $AD=BC$.

Let $G$ be the point of intersection between $DN$ and $AB$.  Using the Law of Sines on the triangle $GFC$ noting that $\angle GFC=\alpha$ and $\angle GCF=\theta$, we get
$$GC=GF\left(\frac{\sin(\alpha)}{\sin(\theta)}\right)\,.$$
We have
$$\frac{GF}{GD}=\frac{AG}{AG+AD}=\frac{AG}{AG+d\sin(\theta)}$$
by the [Angle Bisector Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem).  Therefore, $G=I$ if and only if $AG=GC$, which is equivalent to
$$\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\sin(\alpha)}=\frac{GD}{AG+d\sin(\theta)}\,.$$

The Law of Sines on the triangle $AGD$ gives
$$AG=AD\left(\frac{\cos(\alpha)}{\sin(\alpha+\theta)}\right)=\frac{d\sin(\theta)\cos(\alpha)}{\sin(\alpha+\theta)}$$
and
$$GD=AD\left(\frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\alpha+\theta)}\right)=\frac{d\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\alpha+\theta)}\,.$$
That is, $G=I$ iff
$$\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\sin(\alpha)}=\frac{\cos(\theta)}{\cos(\alpha)+\sin(\alpha+\theta)}\,.\tag{3}$$

Note that 
$$\begin{align}
\cos(\alpha)+\sin(\alpha+\theta)&=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha\right)+\sin(\alpha+\theta)
\\&=2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\theta}{2}-\alpha\right)
\\&=2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\theta}{2}+\alpha\right)\,,
\end{align}$$
where we have implemented the identity $$\sin(x)+\sin(y)=2\sin\left(\dfrac{x+y}{2}\right)\cos\left(\dfrac{x-y}{2}\right)\,.$$
Furthermore, from $\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$, we have
$$\begin{align}\cos(\theta)&=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right)\\&=2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\,.\end{align}$$
That is, (3) is equivalent to
$$\sin(\alpha)=\sin(\theta)\left(\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\theta}{2}+\alpha\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}\right)\,.$$
Combining the last result with (1), we conclude that $G=I$ if and only if $$BC=l=d\sin(\theta)=AD\,.$$